# Event listeners on chrome extension class of buttons doesn't seem to work, or the action of the listener doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, google-chrome-storage

I am trying to make a chrome-extension popup-window whereby an user can add a specific tab's URL or delete one or delete all. The delete all works fine, the add URL does the trick too. However, the 'delete one link' doesn't work at all and I have really been struggling with that department. I hope someone could help me out with this one because I don't know what the problem is. Here are the files:

- popup.js: gist.github.com/kobrajunior/4852f85ae18cfb9edbe542a820b8c107
- popup.html: gist.github.com/kobrajunior/1c26691734c19391c62dc336ed2e1791
- manifest.json: gist.github.com/kobrajunior/78acda830c2d1c384333542422f1494d

I have read on other posts that it may be because the `getElementsByClassName` doesn't return a 'real' array by which you can manipulate things with functions, if that's true, than I'm all out of tools to solve this one.

The 'X' button doesn't work :

[image: The 'X' button doesn't work]

Clear everything buttons works as expected :

[image: Clear everything buttons works as expected]

Comment: Please include your code, a [mcve], **in the question itself**, not just as partial URLs somewhere else. Without clear, known, appropriate licensing, we can not just move that code into the question for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `removeMe()` function you have to remove your DOM element from its parent element. Something like this:

```
function removeMe(i) {
  // remove it from the DOM
  var list = document.getElementsByClassName('items');
  list[i].parentNode.removeChild(list[i]);
  list.splice(i, 1);

  // remove it from chrome-storage
  chrome.storage.local.get({urlList:[], titleList:[]}, function(data) {
     urlList = data.urlList;
     titleList = data.titleList;
     urlList.splice(i, 1);
     titleList.splice(i, 1);

     // update chrome storage
     saveList();
  }); 
}
```

Or you could just use your main `list` id:

```
document.getElementById("list").removeChild(list[i]);
```

Comment: Tried both of them now, still doesn't seem to work. I even added a little 'alert-demo' to see if the event listeners work, that also doesn't work.

Comment: I'm digging deeper in your code! Hold still!

Comment: Why do you use `;` semicolons in `button` tag?
`<button id="add"; tabindex="-1";>Add link</button>`

Comment: but it shouldn't be the problem at all

Comment: No that doesn't matter because when I 'inspect element' on the popup-icon everything works okay. Only the event listeners on the buttons (I think) do not work and I don't have a clue why.

Comment: I even tried to search for solutions conforming the jQuery library and used that, still couldn't solve it (might be because I never used jQuery before).

Comment: I think i got it: you forgot to add eventlisteners to the created "delete" buttons.

Comment: in `restore()` at your `for` loop  you can pass `i` to the `addToDom()` to use it there, to add the `eventListener` to the "X" button, just add a line like this:

`button.addEventListener("click",function() { removeMe(i); });`

Comment: oh really..  in this case i have no idea  sorry...   
unless its the way you implemented the callback function of the eventListener.  It should look like this:    

`allButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() { removeMe(i); });`

Comment: No problem haha, you tried your best. This turned out to be very complex.